# CSS - returning different values from different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I am using jQuery to grab CSS values for objects, each of the browsers (IE, Mozilla, Chrome, etc) returns different values.

For example, in Chrome, a background image (.css("background-image")) returns:

```
url(http://i41.tinypic.com/f01zsy.jpg)
```

Where in Mozilla, it returns:

```
url("http://i41.tinypic.com/f01zsy.jpg")
```

I am having the same problem on other aspects, such as background-size.

In chrome it returns:

```
50% 50%
```

But Mozilla returns:

```
50%+50%
```

My problem with this is, I have functions that split the CSS (background-size), for example based on a space .split("  "), but this could not work on Mozilla because it uses a + instead.

Is there any way that I can fix this problem and make the browsers to use one standard?

Is there any function that I could write which grabs and splits values, based on the type of browser the user is using?

Comment: I can't really think of a situation where you haven't set these css values yourself at some point...

Comment: @NicolasLeThierryd'Ennequin I'm a bit confused. What do you mean?

Comment: For example, the default `background-size` property will be "auto" (or "auto auto"). If you explicitly set `background-size` to another value in your script, it means that know it without having to retrieve it with the `$().css` method. Or are you trying to read the value while the property is being animated?

Comment: @NicolasLeThierryd'Ennequin I am reading the values so that they can be inserted into the database. I am building a website creator, so when the page loads it will retrieve the background data for the user-created page.

Comment: So for example, how does your user set the background size? There will be controls of some kind in the user interface. So that's when the user sets these values that they must be sent to your back-end app to be persisted in the dabatase. You don't have to wait for the page to be rendered and try to read the actual css properties. More generally, it will be better to deal with the actual intended values (given by your user through your UI) that with rendered values that are browser-dependent.

Comment: @NicolasLeThierryd'Ennequin That's exactly how it works. The user interface lets them set the background image, colour, size, position etc, and the CSS values are sent to the database. The problem was that because of different browsers, it wasn't using the data correctly because of the + and " " problem, etc.

Comment: Here's a very basic demo of what I mean: http://jsbin.com/niguta/edit?js,output

Comment: @NicolasLeThierryd'Ennequin I see. Mines is very similar, however once it sets the background, it does: $("something").css("backgroundSize") in order to grab them (if someone edited the value from the text boxes, they could insert bad values into the database.

Comment: Yes, of course you need to do some input validation before writing the values to your database. Anyway, it's much better to do like this than apply the effect then try to read the value afterwards from the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different browsers use different CSS standards and you may have to write a full-blown parser to make them one standard.

Workaround is that you should split or use CSS values taking into account the different browsers standards. Like the CSS(background-size) problem can be solved using this:

```
space.split("\\s|\\+"); //split my string where it either has a space 'or' a plus sign
```

For CSS(background-image), the solution may be to replace the inverted commas before using it:

```
space.replace("\"", "");
```

Try to make the splits generallized for all browsers. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

> My problem with this is, I have functions that split the CSS
>   (background-size), for example based on a space .split(" "), but this
>   could not work on Mozilla because it uses a + instead.

Try adding `\+` to `RegExp` passed to `.split`

`.split(/\s|\+/)`

---

```js
var res = ["50%+50%", "50% 50%"];

var re = /\s+|\+/;

console.log(res[0].split(re), res[1].split(re));
```

Comment: Very nice example. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't the cleanest method, but you could run a string parser for the background image source and delete any quotation marks. This would be the most efficient method for parsing the background image URL. It should work without harming the data because URL's typically can't contain quotation marks, as they are encoded as `%22`

As for the background-size, you could parse the results for + signs and change those to spaces, as + signs typically aren't present as the values for any CSS properties, so you should be relatively safe in taking those out.

In addition, you could check the browser type to see if you'd even have to run these parsings in the first place. As a precaution, you should also see how Opera and Safari return results, and if those are any different, you could create branch statements for the parsers that handle the different types of CSS values returned by the different browsers.

**Note:** The parsing methods I have described attempt the goal of converting the Firefox results to the Chrome-style results.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm going to create some functions that will remove " " from images, and another (as in the answer from guest271314) which removes +

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help.

I'll share the code I have ended up using!

```
cssCommas: function(text)
{
    return text.replace(new RegExp("\"", "g"),"");
},

cssPlus: function(text)
{
    return text.replace(new RegExp("\\+", "g"),"");
},

cssSplit: function(text,removePercent)
{
    var removeParent = removeParent || false;
    if(removePercent == true)
    {
        text = text.replace(new RegExp("%", "g"),"");
    }
    return text.split(new RegExp("\\s|\\+","g"));
},

css: function(text)
{
    return this.cssCommas(this.cssPlus(text));
}
```

Works perfectly on all browsers now. Thanks a lot.